# How to create a whitelist of URLs using a sitemap in robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt, whitelist

I'm trying to create a whitelist of URLs for crawlers to visit (in other words,  I want a list of URLs that crawlers visit, and I want the crawlers to ONLY visit those files).

I've got a sitemap with all the URLs on the whitelist in it.

How should I format the robots.txt?

Does this work?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Sitemap: sitemap.txt
```

Or do I have to do it like this?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: whitelist/*
Sitemap: sitemap.txt
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap and robots.txt are not directly connected. They are different technologies. The robots.txt file is just used to point to the sitemap file. Thats all.

So the first example will not give you the desired result, because crawling of every page is set to Disallow. The second example is correct, and you have to add the domain to the sitemap url

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: whitelist/*
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Some of professional crawlers have the 'ignore robots.txt' option, just like Slickplan, for example. So no need to format the 'robots.txt' file.

Comment: Everybody should know what robots.txt should be used for. And the fact some crawler is not behaving according to that, does not mean, that you should stop following robots.txt specs